# In Spring Boot and Kotlin how can you properly add internationalization?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have been following [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/) tutorial and I can follow it, although I had some issues.

Almost at the end, where it talks about configuration properties, I though it was a good idea to try to set some kind of internationalization to it, with a different file depending on the language, but I have been unable to do so. I only load it on English, no matter how I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [Spring Boot Docs on Internationalization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-internationalization)? I guess it is not that helpful.

Suppose you have your resource bundle like this.

```
- src/main/resources/
  - messages.properties
  - messages_es.properties
  - ...
```

You need to add some configuration:

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    fun localeResolver() = SessionLocaleResolver().apply {
        setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
    }

    @Bean
    fun localeInterceptor() = LocaleChangeInterceptor().apply {
        this.paramName = "lang"
    }

    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor())
    }
}
```

Then an example using `greet.hello` might look like:

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class PageController(val messageSource: MessageSource) {
    @GetMapping("/greet")
    fun greet(): String {
        return messageSource.getMessage("greet.hello", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
    }
}
```

If you do not think this looks pretty, then try using some of Kotlin's features to clean it up.

This is how to choose a language:

```sh
# Use the default
curl --request GET --url 'http://localhost:8080/greet'
# Hello

# Use English
curl --request GET --url 'http://localhost:8080/greet?lang=en'
# Hello

# Use Spanish
curl --request GET --url 'http://localhost:8080/greet?lang=es'
# Hola
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works perfectly. Seems that I have a lot to learn about Spring.